# Variable prediction from known mean and sd

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate weight of fish using length-weight relationship equation as below.

W = aL^b, where
 W = Weight, L = Length and 'a' & 'b' are constants estimated.

I am able to get values for a and b from FishBase website, where they state 95% confident lower and upper value of both constants.

For example, one particular species has this.

**From FishBase:** Bayesian length-weight: a=0.01349 (0.01106 - 0.01645), b=2.95 (2.89 - 3.01)

I understand I can run the formula for combination of three values (i.e. mean, lower and upper) separately and plot to show the variability in estimation of weight.

However, I am more interested in predicting Weight that is expected when mean changes between two bounds. Basically I want R to choose random values for both the constants within the bounds when it estimates the values of weight from the above equation. Can this be possible in R or I am stuck at a dead-end?

```
a <- data.frame (mean=0.01349, min = 0.01106, max = 0.01645) 
b <- data.frame (mean=2.95, min = 2.89, max = 3.01)

FishLength <- data.frame(Length = c(35,40,65,36,49)) 
FishLength$W_est <- (a$mean)*FishLength$Length^b$mean
FishLength$W_min <- (a$min)*FishLength$Length^b$min
FishLength$W_max <- (a$max)*FishLength$Length^b$max
```

Above is something I would run to achieve different estimates but I am not satisfied with this and want to account for variability while estimating weight.

Comment: you mean you want to randomly select a value of the `a, b` coefficients that have certain boundaries???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function
the function below have argument `len` that is the length of the fist, and `a` and `b` cofficients. The function randomly select a coefficient value between 2 boundaries and calculate weight

```
calc <- function(len, a = list(min = 0.01166, max = 0.01645), b = list(min = 2.89, max = 3.01)){
  weigh = runif(1, a[[1]], a[[2]]) * len^runif(1, b[[1]], b[[2]])
  return(weigh)
}

calc(10)
```

returns weight for length 10
 you can hav the result on the figure

```
plot(x = c(0, 20), y = c(0, 100), type = "n")
curve(0.01166*x^2.89, 0, 20, add = T)
curve(0.01645*x^3.01, 0, 20, add = T)
curve(0.01349*x^2.95, 0, 20, add = T, lty = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mateusz1981. I think the function does exactly what I would like to achieve. I haven't known of runif() function before, only was aware of rnorm(). I would just loop the function over all lengths I have in the dataset.